# Test approaches for micro services architecture related application

Tags: test-strategy

We have an application now developing with Micro services architecture. From the testing perspective what sort of testing practices / strategies should follow

Comment: please share some specifics, right now the description is very broad so i could just answer "same best practices as everywhere", test pyramide, risk assessment, test automation.... when you state what makes your setup special or where you expect problems, we can maybe recommend specific tools and strategies for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is somewhat broad there is a lot in common to testing micro services, start by reading the following:

[Testing Strategies in a Microservice Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/)

[Testing Microservices, the sane way](https://medium.com/@copyconstruct/testing-microservices-the-sane-way-9bb31d158c16)

Note that many implementations claiming to use Microservices are simply legacy monolithic application crudely broken into some pieces and are not following any of [The Principles of Microservices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920043935.do) and as such it's hard to refer to them in this context